# Tasks.await() is not returning when expected

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save data into a Firebase RealtimeDatabase.
The process of saving is fine and works just well, but I was curious about an idea I had: To force the `.setValue` operation into a synchronous structure. I know, that that way isn't the best one, but I wanted to try it regardless of that fact.
So I came up with this code:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Tasks.await(databaseReference.child("someChild").setValue(someObject));
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t1.start();
    try {
        t1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("finished");
}
```

In theory, that code snippet is intended to **first** set the value in the Database, then wait for the completion of that (through the `Tasks.await()`), and then print out **after that* the line "finished".
I wrapped the `Tasks.await()`-command in a second thread because when I don't, I get an exception which says something like "Tasks.await() must not be called in the main application thread".

But when I run the whole thing, it just gets stuck at `t1.join();`.
When I delete the `t1.join();`-statement, everything works just fine, but the second Thread (t1) isn't finished before the "finished"-output is there. I know why this is like that, but I am nontheless interested in a solution to that problem.

Comment: How do you know that `Tasks.await()` returns when you don't use `join`?

Comment: I tested that specifically with another `System.out.println();`

Comment: Ok, and if "you know why this is like that" please share with us.

Comment: @Oleg The thing is, that it needs some time to load the Object into the Database. And because Firebase Database works asynchronous, the `Tasks.await()` just returns when the saving of the object is finished. And in that specific case, the saving of the object does take longer than the simple `System.out.println("finished")`-call.

Comment: Maybe it's because of  what's described here -
 https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#threading you have a listener that is supposed to run on the main thread which is blocked by join.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean, that I would get the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not be called on the main application thread` (which I also get, when I run `Tasks.await();` directly in the mainthread and not in `t1`?

Comment: No, this is relevant only for `Tasks.await()` itself the `onComplete` listener runs on the main thread by default.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Is there a way to solve this e.g. by moving the `onComplete` listener to `t1`?

Comment: You can try adding an `Executor` to the task, it's described in the link I posted earlier.

Comment: Okay, I tried it by wrapping the `Tasks.await()` in the executor, but it didn't really work. Now the `t1.join()` doesn't wait for the other thread at all, it just moves on.

Comment: I don't understand why you are even using a thread here along with Tasks.await().  Firebase APIs are asynchronous and require no special threading.  If you want to do something after a Task completes, just add a completion listener on that task that will get invoked when the work is done.

Comment: @DougStevenson The thing is, that I more or less need a synchronous structure in this use case, because I want to save data initially and then do other stuff. I could solve this with the completion listener. But  let's say I need five different objects saved as different children one after another (and for whatever reason I decide to use onComplete for every .setValue-call). Then I would have 5 instances of onComplete nested in each other. And the approach I came up with would make solve the problem without getting to messy (if it would work).

Comment: Just attach a completion listener to the Task returned by Tasks.await().

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I am sorry, but I don't really know, what exactly you are suggesting. Could you specify that please?

Comment: Tasks.await() returns another Task object.  That Task can take a success listener just like any other Task.  That listener will be invoked when all the other tasks are themselves completed successfully.  So if you want to do some work only when all the other tasks are complete, use that.